# How to infer parameter type of a overloaded callback?

Tags: typescript, callback, type-safety

I'm trying to define a type-safe nodejs-style callback in typescript. I would like to have `err` defined as `Error` if present or `data` as `T` if not.

1. If I use this code

```
export interface SafeCallback<T> {
    (err: unknown): void;
    (err: undefined, data: T): void;
}

const subscribe = <T>(callback: SafeCallback<T>) => {
    let result: T;
    try {
        // result = something
    } catch (e) {
        callback(e);
        return;
    }

    callback(undefined, result);
};

subscribe<{id: string}>((err, data?) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(data.id);
    }
});
```

I get `'data' is of type 'unknown'.`

2. If I remove the question mark from `data` I get
   `Argument of type '(err: undefined, data: { id: string; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SafeCallback<{ id: string; }>'`

I tried both cases defining `err: Error` in the first overload but it didn't change anything.

Anything else I should try?

Thanks!

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8BxEm) is the closest I can get and have it be type safe.  Anything else I tried has run into limitations or bugs.  Does it work for your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey! Feel free to post as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with a conditionnal type may be ?

```
export type SafeCallback<T> = {
    <errorType>(err: errorType, data: errorType extends undefined ? T : null): void;
};


const subscribe = <T>(callback: SafeCallback<T>) => {
    let result: T;
    try {
      // result logic
    } catch (e) {
        callback(e, null);
        return;
    }

    callback(undefined, result);
};

subscribe<{ id: string }>((err, data) => {
    if (data !== null) {
        console.log("data  = " + data.id);
    } else {
        console.log("err = " + err);
    }
});
```

edit :
just seeing @jcalz reply. Taking something from his response :

```
export interface SafeCallback3<T> {
    <errorType>(...args:( errorType extends undefined ? [err: undefined, data: T] : [err: errorType] )): void;
}
```

which prevent to cast error in catch.

```
const subscribe3 = <T>(callback: SafeCallback3<T>) => {
    let result: T;
        try {
        // ...
        } catch (e) {
            callback(e);
            return;
    }

    callback<undefined>(undefined, result);
};

subscribe3<{ id: string }>((...args) => {
  const [err, data] = args;
  if (!err) {
    console.log(data.id);
  } else {
    err.message
  }
});
```